# is there a way to call a key event handle of a form in another form? C# windows forms

Tags: c#, .net

so I have two forms one for managing data and one for entering data, i want the data management form to be able to refresh the datagridview while entering data from the other form.

that's the code that i use to refresh the datagridview in the management form (formA)

```
private void Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable DT = CLASS_SUPPLIERS.SP_SELECTSUPPLIER();
            dgvSup.DataSource = DT;
        }
```

i want to be able to use that refrech_click in formB which is data entry form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your Form2 pass in a reference to the form that needs to be refreshed.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
```

Your form2 constructor then stores this

```
public Form2: Form
{

    FormA ToBeUpdatedForm { get; }
    ...  

    public Form2(FormA fa)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ToBeUpdatedForm = fa;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it when you need

```
this.ToBeUpdatedForm.Refresh_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: I can't implement this, can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @R0M4N I updated based on your updated post.  If this does not then you need to be more specific.

Comment: i can't thank you enough, thank you for this jason you saved my life. <3